# Javascript combo box multiple values

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function called bodyStyle() which accepts 5 values:

`bodyStyle(textCol, backCol, heading1Col, headingsCol, linkCol)`

These parameters accept 5 different colours and apply them to the page.

Currently I am using images, as shown:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="bodyStyle('#444','white','#0424B5','#0424B5','#99975A');">
<img src="images/accessibility/bgcolour1.gif" alt="Black Text, White Background" /></a>
```

I am trying to move this to a combo box, and currently have the following:

```
<select name="colours" onchange="bodyStyle(accessibility.colours.value, accessibility.colours.value, accessibility.colours.value, accessibility.colours.value, accessibility.colours.value);">
   <option value='-1'>Select</option>
   <option value='#444','white','#0424B5','#0424B5','#99975A'>Black on White</option>
   <option value='black','yellow','black','black','black'>Black on Yellow</option>
   <option value='black','#87CEFA', 'black','black','black'>Black on Blue</option>
</select>
```

I know this is wrong but I really have no idea, I need to accept the 5 values into bodyStyle()'s parameters.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the quotes and write it down like a single string

```
<select name="colours" onchange="changeColour()">
   <option value='-1'>Select</option>
   <option value='#444,white,#0424B5,#0424B5,#99975A'>Black on White</option>
   <option value='black,yellow,black,black,black'>Black on Yellow</option>
   <option value='black,#87CEFA, black,black,black>Black on Blue</option>
</select>
```

Then you do:

```
function changeColour(){
    var values = document.getElementsByName("colours")[0].value.split(',');
    bodyStyle(values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3], values[4]);
}
```

Something like that

Comment: Glad it worked! If this anwser is correct the please mark is as solved, so if in the future someone comes with the same problem knows it's solved. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

i think these 5 paramters is for applying style.

why dont you make a style class  with that 5 paramter and pass

that class name as the value of that select option

Comment: thanks for the answer, however i'd really prefer to use javascript instead of switching style classes